# Saving a text File in visual basic

Tags: vb.net

I have an onLoad form that is basically an input textbox and an OK/Cancel button. When the OK button is click, I have the code

strFileName = textbox1.text

me.close()

In one of my modules I have the public string strFileName

My question is that if I don't put a string in that textbox and let it get to my main form. When I click save, my save dialog will properly save my code. But if I enter a string with a .txt extension into the onLoad textbox.text, a textfile will not be created, or at least I can't find where it is created. How do I get it work with entering info into that textbox?

```
    Imports System.IO



Public Class Form1
Private employee As EmployeeInfo

Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
    txtFirstName.Clear()
    txtMiddleName.Clear()
    txtLastName.Clear()
    txtEmployeeNumber.Clear()
    cbDepartment.SelectedIndex = -1
    cbDepartment.Text = String.Empty
    txtTelephone.Clear()
    txtExtension.Clear()
    txtEmailAddress.Clear()

    txtFirstName.Focus()
End Sub

Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub btnSaveRecord_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSaveRecord.Click
    employee.firstName = txtFirstName.Text
    employee.middleName = txtMiddleName.Text
    employee.lastName = txtLastName.Text
    If Not Decimal.TryParse(txtEmployeeNumber.Text, employee.employeeNumber) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number.")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    employee.department = cbDepartment.Text
    employee.telephone = txtTelephone.Text Then
    employee.extension = txtExtension.Text
    employee.emailAddress = txtEmailAddress.Text

    If strFileName = String.Empty Then
        If sfdSaveFile.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
            strFileName = sfdSaveFile.FileName
            SaveDocument()
        Else
            SaveDocument()
        End If
    End If




End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim onLoad As New onLoad
    onLoad.ShowDialog()
End Sub


Sub SaveDocument()
    Dim outputFile As StreamWriter

    If Not File.Exists(strFileName) Then
            Try
                outputFile = File.CreateText(strFileName)

                outputFile.WriteLine(employee.firstName)
                outputFile.WriteLine(employee.middleName)
                outputFile.WriteLine(employee.lastName)
                outputFile.WriteLine(employee.employeeNumber)
                outputFile.WriteLine(employee.department)
                outputFile.WriteLine(employee.telephone)
                outputFile.WriteLine(employee.extension)
                outputFile.WriteLine(employee.emailAddress)

                outputFile.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("Error Creating File")
            End Try

        Else
            Try
                outputFile = File.AppendText(strFileName)

                outputFile.WriteLine(employee.firstName)
                outputFile.WriteLine(employee.middleName)
                outputFile.WriteLine(employee.lastName)
                outputFile.WriteLine(employee.employeeNumber)
                outputFile.WriteLine(employee.department)
                outputFile.WriteLine(employee.telephone)
                outputFile.WriteLine(employee.extension)
                outputFile.WriteLine(employee.emailAddress)

                outputFile.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("Error Opening File")
            End Try

        End If


End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: There is way too much code here. How much do you actually need to include in order to provide enough information to help us help you? Wouldn't you have the same issue with just 1 TextBox? Wouldn't it look nicer if the question needn't be scrolled to be read? Please edit this question to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And in the future please keep this in mind. Welcome to SO!

Comment: I will keep that in mind for further inquiries. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If a global variable is not working as per your requirement, you can create some property in onload form later which can be used in form_load to set local variable.

Comment: i guess I could try a set and get. What is the default folder that a text file such as tester.txt would go to if I just try to debug and see if it's my code or if its my variable

Comment: It should be in project's bin\Debug folder.

Comment: well i guess i've narrowed it down, its not the variable. It's not saving any file in the bin\debug folder. any suggestions on what to do next?

Comment: i've been stuck for too long.